# Smack API 4.0 encounter error "org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory" and "Cannot instantiate XMPPConnection"

Tags: java, smack

I'm writing the XMpp connection to my XMpp server by Eclipse added Smack API **4.0**

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;



public class XmppManager {

    public static final String HOST = "localhost";
    public static final int PORT = 5222;
    public static final String SERVICE = "chat";


    public static void main (String[] arg){
        ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(XmppManager.HOST, XmppManager.PORT,
                XmppManager.SERVICE);


    }


}
```

, but during on this, I encounter the error as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration.processConfigFile(SmackConfiguration.java:321)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration.processConfigFile(SmackConfiguration.java:316)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration.<clinit>(SmackConfiguration.java:148)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.<init>(ConnectionConfiguration.java:65)
    at Snapp.XmppManager.main(XmppManager.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Besides, adding XMPPConnection under line  ""Cannot instantiate XMPPConnection""

```
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection (connConfig);
```

Java_Eclipse inform "Cannot instantiate XMPPConnection" error

Have you experienced two issues as above before ? Please help me figure out the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory

You need to have [XPP3](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/xsoap/xpp/mxp1/) in your classpath.

> Besides, adding XMPPConnection under line ""Cannot instantiate
>   XMPPConnection""

Use `XMPPTCPConnection` instead of `XMPPConnection` in Smack 4.

Comment: Hi Flow, just would need your help, after call function XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);
  connection.connect();   // the "connection.connect" show errors, please help me figure out the issue ."Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Unhandled exception type SmackException
 Unhandled exception type IOException
 Unhandled exception type XMPPException

 at Snap.Connection.main(Connection.java:20)"

Comment: You need to handle the exception (and also read some more about Java and Exceptions).